# Using marshal_load with OpenStruct

Tags: ruby, openstruct

How do I use OpenStruct's marshal_load utility? It doesn't appear to work as intended.

The docs give [this example](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-marshal_load), but it doesn't appear to work.

```
require 'ostruct'

event = OpenStruct.new
hash = { 'time' => Time.now, 'title' => 'Birthday Party' }
event.marshal_load(hash)
event.title # => nil
```

If not this way, how do I load a hash into an OpenStruct (without using the constructor)?

For context: I'm loading a hash in from a YAML file and loading it into an existing instance of an OpenStruct subclass.

Comment: +1, nice question. Maybe it is time to send a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `marshal_load` method exists to provide support for `Marshal.load`.

```
event = OpenStruct.new({ 'time' => Time.now, 'title' => 'Birthday Party' })
binary = Marshal.dump(event)
loaded = Marshal.load(binary) # the OpenStruct
```

The easiest way to programmatically load a hash into a struct is using send:

```
event = OpenStruct.new
hash.each do |key, value|
  event.send("#{key}=", value)
end
```

Comment: I understand the original intent of providing this method, but its still not working as expected. The posted example is directly from the docs.

That being said, I ended up overriding the marshal_laod method in my OpenStruct subclass and using `send` to load the hash.

Answer (score 5):

Try with a symbol based hash. That worked for me.

```
#works.rb

hash = { :time => Time.now, :title => 'Birthday Party' }
event.marshal_load(hash)
```

Comment: Interesting! Its not what's documented, but I confirmed it works. YAML.load_file returns string keys, but they can be converted to symbols before loading, I reckon.